# printing swt browser contents with Header and Footer

Tags: java, browser, printing, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am implementing SWT Browser in RCP application for displaying HTML pages.
For Printing we use JavaScript function - `htmlBrowser.execute("javascript:print()");`

This works fine but my problem is that I want a my own Header with Logo and Footer (some text)
on print pages. please help me with suitable example

Answer (score 1):

The only possible solution I can think of.

1. Open a new `Browser`
2. Get the text (`browser.getText()`) from the parent `Browser`
3. Wrap it in your header and footer `html`
4. Set the text (`browser.setText()`) on newly opened `Browser`
5. Hide it  - `shell.setVisible(false)`   (Only if you don't want to show the popup)
6. And invoke `browser.execute("javascript:print()");`

I suspect printing the content after hiding the `Shell`. But, you can give it a try!!